# Should I index my mysql foregin keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am using mysql as DB for my Laravel app.

In one table I have 5 fields that are foregin keys, those FK's points to 5 other tables primary keys.

Right now I have only marked them as FK, but do I need to put a index on every FK as well? Or does a FK count as a index?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql when making a FK it automatically indexes that column(s).

MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint. index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

You can read more here at [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks, but can one FK in table 1 reference two different tables/primary keys in table 2 and tabe 3?

Lets say that I have FK 'seller_id' in table 1. Then I want do make two inner joins using 'seller_id'. Joning 'seller_id' into tables 2s 'user_id' and also join 'seller_id' into tables 3s 'u_info_id'

Comment: No, seller_id is FK in table 1. And then I join seller_id into table 2 and 3s PK

Comment: I dont follow...You are making your PK composite?  For example PK for table 2 is (user_id, seller_id)...